# Corrupted zipfile after curl request

Tags: bash, curl, qualtrics

I am using the [Qualtrics API](https://api.qualtrics.com/docs/create-response-export) to retrieve survey data at scheduled intervals. Below is my shell script (bash) `get_responses.sh` which posts the export, measures the download completion rate, gets the export, and stores/unzips the file.

```
STARTDATE=$(date -v-7d "+%Y-%m-%d")
STARTDATESTRING=$STARTDATE"T00:00:00-07:00:00"
ENDDATE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
ENDDATESTRING=$ENDDATE"T00:00:00-07:00:00"

result=$(curl -X POST -H 'X-API-TOKEN: MYAPITOKEN' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "surveyId": "SV_000000000000",
    "startDate": "startDate": "'"$STARTDATESTRING"'",
    "endDate": "endDate": "'"$ENDDATESTRING"'",
    "format": "csv",
    "useLocalTime": true,
    "useLabels": true
}' "https://myorg.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseexports")

es_id=$(echo "$result" | /usr/local/Cellar/jq/1.5_2/bin/jq --raw-output '.result.id')

curl -H "X-API-TOKEN: MYAPITOKEN" "https://myorg.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseexports/${es_id}"

curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-API-TOKEN: MYAPITOKEN" "https://myorg.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseexports/${es_id}/file" -o "/Users/myname/Desktop/WEA/response.zip"

unzip "/Users/myname/Desktop/WEA/response.zip" -d "/Users/myname/Desktop/WEA/"
```

I intermittently get the following error-

> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>   100   339  100   133  100   206    165    256 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   256
>   {"result":{"percentComplete":0.0,"file":null,"status":"in progress"},"meta":{"httpStatus":"200 - OK","requestId":"2c55524c-03aa-495c-8de7-b54d5b441b34"}}  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>   100   129  100   129    0     0    405      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   405
>
> End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
>   a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
>   latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
>   the last disk(s) of this archive.
>
> unzip:  cannot find zipfile
>   directory in one of /Users/myname/Desktop/response.zip or
>           /Users/myname/Desktop/WEA/response.zip.zip, and cannot find /Users/myname/Desktop/WEA/response.zip.ZIP, period.

The odd part is that this error usually only occurs when I first run the script. If I rerun it, without making any changes, it will go through with no errors. To my understanding this error message means a corrupted zip file. Am I corrupting the POST request by saving it into a variable? I need to capture the post request output somehow as it provides the `es_id` that I need for the subsequent GET request. I would hard code it but the `es_id` refreshes weekly.

Comment: My guess is that the reason your zip file is invalid is because the export hasn't completed.  You need to put https://myorg.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseexports/${es_id} inside a loop and check the result to see if the export is complete before downloading the zip.

Comment: @T.Gibbons You are correct, I incorrectly assumed thats what the second curl command was doing given the response export status documentation [here](https://api.qualtrics.com/docs/get-response-export-progress). But I've gone back and seen all successful pulls have `percentComplete:100` while all unsuccessful pulls have `percentComplete:0` as seen above. Why would running the code initially fail to complete, but rerunning it yields a full pull?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. My guess would be that something gets cached on the first attempt, so the second attempt runs faster.

Comment: That seems likely, when I run this same task using the python code provided in the documentation, the first call takes significantly longer than the second, third, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @T.Gibbons advice I was able to eliminate the error on the initial run by incorporating a while loop into the script.

```
STARTDATE=$(date -v-7d "+%Y-%m-%d")
STARTDATESTRING=$STARTDATE"T00:00:00-07:00:00"
ENDDATE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
ENDDATESTRING=$ENDDATE"T00:00:00-07:00:00"
post_response=$(curl -X POST -H 'X-API-TOKEN: MYAPITOKEN' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "surveyId": "SV_00000000000000",
    "startDate": "'"$STARTDATESTRING"'",
    "endDate": "'"$ENDDATESTRING"'",
    "format": "csv",
    "useLocalTime": true,
    "useLabels": true
}' "https://myorg.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseexports")

es_id=$(echo "$post_response" | /usr/local/Cellar/jq/1.5_2/bin/jq --raw-output '.result.id')

percent_complete=0
while [ $percent_complete -ne 100 ]
do
    response=$(curl -H "X-API-TOKEN: MYAPITOKEN" "https://myorg.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseexports/${es_id}")
    percent_complete=$(echo "$response" | /usr/local/Cellar/jq/1.5_2/bin/jq --raw-output '.result.percentComplete')
done

curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-API-TOKEN: MYAPITOKEN" "https://myorg.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseexports/${es_id}/file" -o "/Users/myname/Desktop/WEA/response.zip"

unzip "/Users/myname/Desktop/WEA/response.zip" -d "/Users/myname/Desktop/WEA"

rm "/Users/myname/Desktop/WEA/response.zip"
```